# Index ..."Async" action name in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure what is the correct way to use Async notation in MVC 5 views...

Suppose we have

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Let suppose at a point we updated the `Home`'s `Index` action from

```
public ActionResult Index() { }
```

to

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
```

Should we rename the action as `IndexAsync` or better to let it as `Index`, because we should now rename all the hardcoded "Index" occurences in "IndexAsync" but as from the route we should redirect by default to the controller `Index` Action, but now Home Index is renamed in `IndexAsync`... What is the recommended practice here?

Comment: The `Async` suffix is just a convention. You don't need to use it.